# CType being evaluated before the rest of expression

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write the return statement of my function like this

```
Return (Not IsDbNull(result)) And (CType(result, String) = "1")
```

However, when `result` is `DbNull`, it throws me an `InvalidCastException`

Writing `(Not IsDbNull(result)) And 2/0 = 1` in my watch works so it seems to me like the `CType` function has something special that makes it be evaluated before the rest of expression.

am I seeing things or CType doesn't respect the evaluation order in VB.NET? Is there a way around this problem that doesn't involve splitting my expression into several parts and assigning them into variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should almost always use [`AndAlso`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) instead of `And`  (and `OrElse` instead of `Or`).

> A logical operation is said to be **short-circuiting** if the compiled
>   code can bypass the evaluation of one expression depending on the
>   result of another expression. If the result of the first expression
>   evaluated determines the final result of the operation, **there is no
>   need to evaluate the second expression**

[`And`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh.aspx) on the other hand will evaluate both expression which causes this exception:

> In a `Boolean` comparison, the `And` operator **always evaluates both
>   expressions**

You could also use [`Convert.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh(v=vs.110).aspx) that treats `Nothing` or `DbNull` as empty string:

```
Return Convert.ToString(result) = "1"
```

Comment: Indeed, AndAlso works, but I thought I was testing against that with the 2/0 operation

Comment: @EduardoWada: i havent tested it, but i think thats caused by another VB.NET oddity: if you use `2/0` you don't get an expected `DivideByZeroException` because that is not an integer division(as it was in C#). VB.NET treats it as a double which results in infinity. If you use the VB.NET integer divison operator it should cause the expected exception: `2\0`

Answer (score 2):

In your case - converting to `string` - you don't need `DbNull` checking and converting to string.
Code below will be enough.

```
Return result.ToString().Equals("1")
```

Because `DbNull.ToString()` returns empty string.

In case `result` returned by `ExecuteScalar` - where `Nothing(null)` value is possible, as pointed out by Tim Schmelter, you can add validation for null

```
Dim checkedResult = If(result, String.Empty)
Return checkedResult.ToString().Equals("1")
```

Or use static `Object.Equals` method

```
Return Equals(result, "1")
```

If `result` is item of `DataRow` type then suggest using extension method for converting values to the proper type

```
Dim value As Integer = datarow.Field(Of Integer)("IntegerColumnName")
Dim value As String = datarow.Field(Of String)("StringColumnName")
```

`DataRow` will return empty string if value is `DbNull`

Comment: Well, it's possible that `result` is a null reference, in that case your approach throws an exception. For example if `result` is what `ExecuteScalar` returned. It can be `DbNull` if the value was a `NULL` value in the database or `null` if there was no value (so nothing returned, no mathing record). [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Comment: DbNull.ToString() being empty string is a useful observation, in my case, my query will always return a row

Comment: @EduardoWada: better use `Convert.ToString(result) = "1"`, edited my answer